# How does a hemisphere's curved surface look unfolded?

Tags: surfaces, spheres

The cylinder's curved looks like a rectangle when unfolded. Since, the cylinder and hemisphere have the same formula for curved surface area - $2\pi r * h$, I assume the hemisphere will also form a rectangle when unfolded similar to [how the area of a circle is determined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQInd.jpg). However, I can not understand how to unfold the hemisphere. [A diagram I made to understand the thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDEAA.jpg).

Comment: A cylinder is flat (curvature 0), so can be unrolled to a piece of paper. A hemisphere is curved, so cannot.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but probably of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4345667/deriving-surface-area-of-a-sphere-using-triangles

Comment: see what happens when you peel off half an orange, and then try to flatten it.  it will crack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cylinder and a hemisphere do *NOT* have the same curved surface.  The Gaussian curvature of a sphere is $1/r$ and that of the cylinder is $0$.  A cylinder can be unrolled onto a plane whereas a sphere cannot (without ripping or stretching).