Shape of a flattened wedge from the surface of a sphere (3Blue1Brown video)

In this video of 3B1B, he shows flattening of "triangular" wedges from the sphere.
Lets take one wedge, and label the top pole as A, lower left corner as B, low right corner as C and the mid point of B and C (which is on the equator), as O. Now consider their positions relative to each other after flattening. 
By thickness logic (as he mentions in his video), we can definitely say that the left and right edges would be as shown (bulging outwards). But what about the lower edge? If we conside the distances AB, AC and AO, they all should be equal. So this shows that the lower edge should also be bulging outwards. So according to me, the final flattened wedge should be like a triangle with its all the edges bulging outwards. (The curvature function of lower bulge may be different than the left/right ones)  
Can someone throw light upon this? In fact looking back, I am not even sure if its possible to flatten the wedge completely in 2D.
EDIT: Link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYQVlVoWoPY&ab_channel=3Blue1Brown
Also, the context in the video is that we are flattening the sphere wedge (maybe made of paper), on a 2D surface (of course without tearing the wedge). At least thats what I got. Anyways, my question is with this context.

Could you add a link to the video, please?

The title in that image suggests that the flattened slices have the same area as those on the sphere, but of course cannot be congruent to them.

@Intelligentipauca made the edits


I see a wedge that goes all the way from one pole to the opposite pole. Your points B and C are merely half way along the two curved edges. 2. You can't really flatten any part of a sphere perfectly. Some part will have to be distorted. Here the distance from the flattened "equator" to the flattened "pole" is non-uniform.


@DavidK your 1st point really makes it clear. Your 2nd point does make intuitive sense to me, will need to define "flat-ability" of a surface to prove it rigorously I guess.

The video explains how the width of each "triangular" shape at a distance $h$ from the base is computed. In this way the area of the "flattened" wedge is the same as the area of the spherical wedge. But those two shapes are not congruent, as your observation proves.

@Intelligentipauca how does the width being equal suffice? If the two shapes are not congruent its not obvious why the area of both shapes would be same

Just think of both shapes divided into many thin horizontal stripes.

Possibly of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4345667/deriving-surface-area-of-a-sphere-using-triangles

@AndrewD.Hwang the discussion under the accepted answer is exactly what I needed! Thanks!
